Magneto error: "Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider"
So when I install Magento using DirectAdmin all goes well. When I go to the website I get the error "Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider".
I have checked these forums for sollutions especially this one: Magento 2: "Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider"
But, I have no idea what the author of the top-comment means, and how to actually fix it. I know some basics but I forgot most of what I learned yeaaaars ago. Can anyone tell me in simple language and instructions on how to fix this?

This message is about the permissions of your files in are directory. Which can be fixed through
Log in to your SSH/CLI with admin permissions and navigate to the root of your store.
Set permissions to the files:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Set permissions to the directories:
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Set permissions to special directories:
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

